# Insufficient space to create shadow copy

Tags: windows, backup, disk-image

The disk I’m trying to make the backup on has more than enough space (in theory) for a full image of my C drive, but every time I do it gets returned with "not enough space to create shadow copy"

Logs in event viewer were unhelpful as they just told me to free up space on an already empty drive that has more than enough space for a backup.

Any tips are appreciated

[Selected drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcFZr.png)

[Disk management screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH19R.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOJYI.png)

Comment: The simplest solution may be to use a different backup program such as Macrium Reflect Free. That way, if you still want to use Windows to make an image then you will have a backup if attempting to make the Windows backup program work damages the data.

Comment: Which disk are you trying to back up to?

Comment: @DavidPostill C to F, and as you can see F has more than enough space.....

Comment: @De_ - It does not have ENOUGH space, it's barely bigger than the source disk, and there is some overhead when it comes to VSS. There are better solutions than the built-in tools to create a system image that does NOT have the same limited options and requirements and certainly will have more capabilities to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Ramhound Isn't the shadow copy problem for the source drive? And if so, might it be for a drive other than C:, e.g., "Windows Recovery Environment (System)"?